# Java upcast scope resolution issue

Tags: java

I have a base class "Shapes" and an extended class "Circle".  Both have a getName method.
My test class is the "Driver" class.

I upcast a Circle object to Shapes and pass it to a function called polyTest.
In that function I want to call getName but I do not want the circle objects implementation of get name to be triggered but instead want the base classes implementation to be triggered.

super.getName() does not work.

My code is bellow.

```
public class Driver{
     public static String polyTest (Shapes s){
        return s.getName(); 
       /*Instead of s.getName()... (gives me the Circle class implementation of getName() )
       I want to call s.Shapes::GetName, the base class implementation of getName. */
     }

     public static void main(String[] args){
      Circle c = new Circle();

      //Test Basic inheritance & basic polymorphism.
      //System.out.print(c.getName());

      //Upcast test.
      Shapes s = (Shapes) c;
      System.out.print( polyTest(s) );    
     }
}

public class Circle extends Shapes{
     Circle(){
      super();
     }

     public String getName(){
      return "I am a Circle";
     }
}

public abstract class Shapes{
     Shapes (){
     }

     public String getName(){
      return "I am a Shape";
     }
}
```

Comment: Looks like that something is wrong in design. BTW, you don't need to upcast to `Shapes`. What do you want to do?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's just the way polymorphism Java works, I'm afraid. You can't force a virtual method call to be executed non-virtually, outside the method itself (where you can call `super.getName()`). The ability to do so would break encapsulation - for example, a class may validate its arguments in a particular way in an overridden method before calling the super method... if you could get around that and say "I only want to call the original implementation" then you'd be violating the whole purpose of overriding the method in the first place.

You should redesign your code so that you *don't* need to call a particular implementation. The point of polymorphism is to allow subclasses to specialize behaviour without the caller knowing ahead of time what that implementation is.

Of course, if you want a method to be non-overridable, you can make it final.

Comment: [Quote]if you could get around that and say "I only want to call the original implementation" then you'd be violating the whole purpose of overriding the method in the first place.[/Quote] I don't only want to use the base implementation I just wanted to know if I overrode getName whether I would loose access to the original implementation.  In C++, just because I override does not mean that I lose access to the implementation I inherited.  I see I do have access to the orig implementation in the Circle src file but not outside of it... It seems one is stuck with overriden impl. in Java.  Thx.

Comment: Sorry, ran out of chars in my reply.  So, is this indeed the case in Java?  If you override you are stuck with the overridden implementation?

Answer (score 0):

1. You don't need to upcast `Circle` to `Shapes`. (BTW, why `Shapes` but `Circle`?)
2. If you don't want your `Circle` class implement its own `getName` method, just don't override it.
3. If you need to override `getName` method for something else, you may want to add `getNameInSomeContext` to your `Shapes` class, and override it in derived classes if necessary.

Comment: 1. I know I don't need to upcast it, I did so to see if I can axs my inherited implementation.  The prob with oop is that non omnipotent creatures write the code... wanted to see if I lost access to the base implementation... just in case I wanted to use the old implementation for what ever unexpected need.